# Implicit conversion between equivalent interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

Supposing I have the following interface:

```
public interface IMap<S, T>()
{
  T Map(S source);
}
```

Depending on the generic type arguments I'm using, the implementation of working with it could become cumbersome (i.e. `IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>>`)

To simplify things locally, I would prefer to be able to declare an explicitly named version of the interface, such as:

```
public interface IMyMap : IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>> {}
```

No additional methods are required; just something to make working with it less cumbersome (especially if it came down to instantiation by reflection).

However, I also would prefer if I could cast any implementation of `IMap` that has the exact same type arguments, into that specifically named type.  This isn't a C++ Typedef, which would be perfect for what I'm looking for, this is C#.

I could write an implementation that accepts any form of `IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>>`, and wraps the calls.  That seems like it would eventually be more trouble than it's worth when implementing it, though.

Edit: For example, I'm looking to do something along these lines:

```
public class SomeOtherType { }
public interface IMap<S, T> { T Map(S source); }
public interface IMyMap : IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>> {}

public class Main
{
  public Main(IMap<int, IEnumerabel<SomeOtherType>> input)
  {
    IMyMap wrapped = input;
  }
}
```

Obviously, this kind request is critically dependent upon `IMyMap` not having any more definitions than the interface it implements.

The solution that tehDorf provided is in the realm of what I want; however, I was also looking for other possible solutions, such as working through a wrapper:

```
public class MyMapWrapper : IMyMap
{
  private IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>> wrapped;
  public MyMapWrapper(IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>> wrapped)
  { this.wrapped = wrapped; }

  public IEnumerable<SomeOtherType> Map(int source) { return wrapped.Map(source); }
}
```

Are there any other different methods of doing what I'm looking for?  Especially anything that isn't relegated to a single file.

Comment: I think I've got my head around this. And I think that the code you've posted is doing exactly what you're trying to do. You're implementing the adapter pattern. You have a class that implements one interface and you need it to implement a different interface. What you're calling a "wrapper" is an adapter. There's no implicit way to do it.

Comment: The reason why I'm confused is because what tehDorf suggested and using a wrapper are completely unrelated solutions and solve entirely different problems. I don't think there's any way that both of them could potential solutions to the same problem.

Comment: @ScottHannen Apologies, I'm not fully familiar with all the different pattern names out there.  The way I see it is that, in this specific instance, I could use the using alias to define IMyMap as IMap<...> in the same file of a class that consumes and works with an instance of IMyMap - however, the alias only exists in that file.  Alternatively, I could define IMyMap as an interface (project-wide definition instead of local file), use that in the aforementioned class, and use the adapter pattern to wrap any non-IMyMap implementations of IMap that happen to use the exact same type arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) (thanks, [itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86)):

```
using IMyMap = IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>>;
```

Then, in the code you can use `IMyMap`, like so:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IMyMap = SomeExample.IMap<int, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>>;

namespace SomeExample
{
    public interface IMap<T, S>
    {
        T Map(S source);
    }

    public class ExampleUsage
    {
        public IMyMap Foo { get; set; }

        public void SetFoo()
        {
            Foo = (IMyMap) new object();
            Foo = (IMap<int, IEnumerable<bool>>) new object(); // Same thing
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to add the using alias directive to any code file you want to use it in, though.

Comment: It's called a [using alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked. It doesn't cast an `IMap<S, T>` into `IMyMap`

Comment: @Rob The OP wants something to make using `IMap<int, IEnumerable<SomethingElse>>` less cumbersome. They specifically state "This isn't a C++ Typedef, **which would be perfect for what I'm looking for**, this is C#." - which I am interpreting as 'the OP is unaware that there is a similar feature in C# now'. The example of wanting to make another interface was the OP's best guess at what might be possible in C#.

Comment: @Rob I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question - this IS in the realm of the solutions I'm looking for.  I'll revise parts of my question.

Comment: @tehDorf Fair enough. If you'd like to edit your answer slightly (perhaps remove the crossed out text), I'll be able to remove my downvote; since it's currently locked.

Comment: I thought I got it, but apparently not. This doesn't allow you to cast one type as another. It just allows you to pretend - within the scope of one file - that a type has a different name.

Comment: @ScottHannen I already addressed your first point in my previous comment, and Serge agreed that this was inline with the intent of his question. As for the second point, yes that is a drawback I mentioned in my answer. Given the OP's question, it was unclear if this would be a deal-breaker or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public interface IMap<S, T>
{
    T Map(S source);
}

public class SomeClass { }
public class ThatClass { }

public interface IMapOfSomething : IMap<SomeClass, ThatClass> { }

public class Map : IMapOfSomething
{
    ThatClass IMap<SomeClass, ThatClass>.Map(SomeClass source)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can cast `Map` as `IMap` or `IMap<SomeClass, ThatClass>`.
You can cast `IMap` as `IMap<SomeClass, ThatClass>`.

This part is unclear:

> I also would prefer if I could cast any implementation of IMap that has the exact same type arguments, into that specifically named type.

If the class doesn't implement `IMap` - it just happens to have the same properties and methods - then no, you can't cast it as `IMap`. That would be working against the language. The intent is that you would deliberately implement an interface. And if it's deliberate then you would indicate that by declaring that the class implements the interface.

Imagine the trouble you could have if you could cast something as `IMap` *without* actually implementing the interface, just because it had the same properties and methods. You could change that class so that it no longer "looks like" `IMap` but you wouldn't get any compiler errors. The code would fail at runtime.

Comment: I will revise my question to hopefully alleviate the confusion.